# Passing in arguments to method Python interpreter from shell

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning how to use Python. I would like to learn how I can pass in arguments for a function. In Java I know we can use BufferedReader or Scanner to receive user input. How do we get user input with Python? I have a function to print spaces based on user input. How do I do this?

```
def right_justify(s):
    s = " " * 70 - s.len()
    print(s)

right_justify(s)
```

I want to print enough spaces so `s`'s rightmost character appears in the 70th column on the user's screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen from: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/getting-user-input-from-the-keyboard

**Raw_Input**

raw_input is used to read text (strings) from the user:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "your name is: ",name
type(name)
```

output:

```
What is your name? fred
your name is: fred
type 'str'>
```